# Closure of set intersection neighborhood with the closure set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

What's the meaning of the **definition of the closure set** that if (x belongs to A ) the neighborhood of x intersects with A does not empty
I'm trying to prove that the closure of A is the smallest closed set containg A

Comment: Can you state your definition of the closure of a set more clearly. This might help towards the solution to your question.

Answer (score 1):

We have indeed the one definition: $\overline{A}$ is the set of all points of $X$ such that every (open =) neighbourhood $O$ of $x$ intersects $A$, i.e. $O \cap A \neq \emptyset$ for all open subsets $O \subseteq X$ with $x \in O$.

Claim: $\overline{A}$ is the smallest closed subset of $X$ that contains $A$ as a subset.

To see $\overline{A}$ is closed, we show that $X \setminus \overline{A}$ is open. So pick $p \notin \overline{A}$. This means that there is some open set $O_p$ such that $O_p \cap A = \emptyset$. But then for *all* $x \in O_p$, the same $O_p$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ that misses $A$, so all of $O_p$ is not a point of $\overline{A}$, so $p \in O_p \subseteq X \setminus \overline{A}$. So every point of $X \setminus \overline{A}$ is an interior point of it, so $X \setminus \overline{A}$ is open and $\overline{A}$ is closed.

Clearly, every point of $A$ is in $\overline{A}$, because if $x \in A$, and $x \in O$ open, $x \in O \cap A \neq \emptyset$. So $A \subseteq \overline{A}$.

And if $C$ is closed and $A \subseteq C$, we have that $\overline{A} \subseteq C$, showing that $\overline{A}$ is the minimal such closed set: for suppose $p \in \overline{A}$ and $p \notin C$. Then there is some neighbourhood $O_p$ of $p$ that is a subset of $X \setminus C$ (as the latter set is open, and $p$ is in it). But then $O_p \cap A \subseteq O_p \cap C = \emptyset$ and this contradicts $x \in \overline{A}$. So $p \in C$ and we are done.